# How to set a label's buffer color in a mapfile?

Tags: labeling, mapserver, buffer, mapfile

I would like to set a white buffer around labels in a mapfile (Mapserver version 6.2.1). In the official [documentation](http://mapserver.org/fr/mapfile/label.html), I can't find a specific parameter for this... I have tried the `SHADOWCOLOR` and `SHADOWSIZE` parameters but if set with a `OFFSET 0 0`, the shadow is not visible (it has to be offsetted, which I don't want to).

Here is an extrat of my code, to be completed if you have ideas on this issue:

```
    CLASS
        NAME "myLayer"
        EXPRESSION ([code] = 1)
        STYLE
            SYMBOL "STD_circle"
            COLOR 0 255 0
        END
        LABEL
            FONT "vera"                 
            TYPE TRUETYPE
            SIZE 3
            COLOR 0 0 0
            BUFFER 2
        END
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, found myself, and not obvious at all in the documentation: add a `OUTLINECOLOR` to the `LABEL` tags!

```
CLASS
    NAME "myLayer"
    EXPRESSION ([code] = 1)
    STYLE
        SYMBOL "STD_circle"
        COLOR 0 255 0
    END
    LABEL
        FONT "vera"                 
        TYPE TRUETYPE
        SIZE 3
        COLOR 0 0 0
        OUTLINECOLOR 255 255 255
        BUFFER 2
    END
END
```

Comment: Have you any experience with the difference between Buffer and Outline-color/width?